# SQL not summing based on user, but repeating aggregate sum on every line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to sum up won revenue based on user with conditions (Activities created on or after 2/1/21.  Activities are reported on the contact and/or the account level).  I'm trying to sum up won revenue by user.

Any idea?

```
 SELECT s.fullname, s.businessunitidname,
(SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
    FROM Opportunities o
    WHERE   (SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
                FROM Opportunities o
                INNER JOIN SystemUser s ON o.ownerid = s.systemuserid
                INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.accountid = o.customerid
                INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.accountid = c.parentcustomerid
                INNER JOIN activities ac ON c.contactid = ac.regardingobjectid
                WHERE o.statuscode = '3'
                AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid) >0
            AND
                (SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
                FROM Opportunities o
                INNER JOIN SystemUser s ON o.ownerid = s.systemuserid
                INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.accountid = o.customerid
                INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.accountid = c.parentcustomerid
                INNER JOIN activities ac ON c.contactid = ac.regardingobjectid
                WHERE o.createdon >= '2/1/2021'
                AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid)>0
            AND
                (SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
                FROM Opportunities o
                INNER JOIN SystemUser s ON o.ownerid = s.systemuserid
                INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.accountid = o.customerid
                INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.accountid = c.parentcustomerid
                INNER JOIN activities ac ON c.contactid = ac.regardingobjectid
                WHERE ac.createdon >= '2/1/2021'
                AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid)>0
            AND
                (SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
                FROM Opportunities o
                INNER JOIN SystemUser s ON o.ownerid = s.systemuserid
                INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.accountid = o.customerid
                INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.accountid = c.parentcustomerid
                INNER JOIN activities ac ON c.contactid = ac.regardingobjectid
                WHERE  ac.actualend <= '3/31/2021'
                AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid)>0) Revenue,

        
        
FROM Systemuser s
WHERE s.isdisabled = 'false' AND s.businessunitidname != 'USRBP'
```

Data I'm getting:

```
Steve Smith   200
John Hands    200
Alex Trey     200
Mike Toth     200
```

Data I want:

```
Steve Smith 130
John Hands  90
Alex Trey   402
Mike Toth   98
```

Comment: Conditions 2 and 3 look identical. What exact logic are you trying to achieve, unclear? `AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid` seems superfluous, or putting it another way: the `inner join SystemUser` seems wrong

Comment: Also, will any `Opportunities` for a particular `SystemUser` have all those tables to be joined, or are the joins only valid for the conditions?

Comment: Please show sample data, actual results and expected results as formatted text.

Comment: @charlieface I'm trying to connect the owner id on the opportunity table with the id on the system table.  Also, Opportunities are connected with the SystemUser, but Account table is connected with Opportunities, and the contact table connects with the account table.  Activities are associated with the contact table only.  conditions 2 and 3 are pulling from different tables (o vs. ac)

Comment: Yeah sorry realized that it was different tables afterwards. What is the join logic, do you want `Opportunites` even if there is no associated `Accounts` `contacts` etc?

Comment: Need starting sample data in addition to expected results.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if the joins in the `WHERE` sub-queries would be wrong if they were part of the main `SELECT SUM` subquery.

Assuming it is OK then you can simplify this down to a `HAVING` with conditional `SUM` aggregation.

- Note that your original query didn't work properly anyway, as `SystemUser` was rejoined again, therefore the final `AND o.ownerid = s.systemuserid` was referring to the wrong table reference.

```sql
SELECT
    s.fullname,
    s.businessunitidname,
    (SELECT SUM(o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct)
        FROM Opportunities o
        INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.accountid = o.customerid
        INNER JOIN contacts c ON a.accountid = c.parentcustomerid
        INNER JOIN activities ac ON c.contactid = ac.regardingobjectid
        WHERE o.ownerid = s.systemuserid
        HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN o.statuscode = '3'
            THEN o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct END) > 0
           AND SUM(CASE WHEN o.createdon >= '2/1/2021'
            THEN o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct END) > 0
           AND SUM(CASE WHEN ac.createdon >= '2/1/2021'
            THEN o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct END) > 0
           AND SUM(CASE WHEN ac.actualend <= '3/31/2021'
            THEN o.tru_totalgrossrevenuefromusrbpoppproduct END) > 0
    ) Revenue
FROM Systemuser s
WHERE s.isdisabled = 'false' AND s.businessunitidname != 'USRBP'
```

Comment: Thank you @charlieface.  It is much cleaner but doesn't solve my issue unfortunately.  Still receiving the same sum among all users.   I would need to sum up the gross revenue based on who owns that opportunity.

Comment: Getting closer @charlieface.  Will this add only the revenue from opportunities where it meets EVERY condition in the cases?

Comment: Yes only where the user matches all conditions, otherwise `NULL` will be returned for that user. That is what you seemed to want, is that not correct?